# Stream output of aws cli sync command to powershell host

Tags: powershell, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm using Powershell to write a folder synchronization tool to copy files from a local folder up to AWS S3 with the AWS CLI.

The script works as I can see files show up in S3, but the output of the `aws sync` command does not appear on screen (normally when `aws sync` is run from the command line it shows each file as it it uploads, the current status of all files/count, etc).

How do I get that to happen inside a Powershell script?

Here are some various things I've tried, but none of which worked:

```
aws s3 sync $local_folder $aws_bucket

$awsio = aws s3 sync $local_folder $aws_bucket

#Out-Host -InputObject $awsio
Write-Output $awsio
```

Comment: So just nothing shows up in powershell? But the command does what it's supposed to? How do you call your script?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer was the first thing I tried which was just the normal command on its own line:

`aws s3 sync $local_folder $aws_bucket`

I think what happened is when I first tried that, it was doing something in the background before actually starting to run.  So if I had waited longer I would have seen output appear on screen as I expected...